# BLOB vs VARBINARY - space and performance

Tags: mariadb

If there is column with type `VARBINARY(1024)` and content is 1-2 bytes, what space will be allocated on disk? Is it always 1024 bytes or variable size? Probably `BLOB` type is better choice. There is no index on this column but rows can be 10M or more.

Comment: VARBINARY(1024) can store up to 1024 bytes. It takes actual amount of bytes + 2 bytes for the value length + 1 byte for NULL marker. Short strings are stored within the table data, for long strings (approx. over 765 bytes) the reminder is stored in oversize data space. *rows can be 10M or more.* In strict mode the attempt to store the value longer than 1024 bytes will fail, in non-strict mode the value will be truncated with according warning.

Comment: @Akina In other words, if real data is 200 bytes, is there difference in used disk space if column definition is `VARBINARY(1024)` or `VARBINARY(512)`?

Comment: No difference for such data.

Answer (score 1):

`BLOB` is limited to 64KB; `VARBINARY(1024)` is limited to 1024 bytes.  Otherwise, they are stored, optimized, and processed the same:

- 2-byte "length" prefix.
- Stored "on-record" if short enough, else stored "off-record".  The algorithm depends on other wide columns, etc, in the row.  Off-record has a slight impact on disk space and a potentially big impact on performance due to an extra I/O (unless cached).
- `BLOB` will not attempt to optimize a query using in-memory storage and sorting; I'm not sure about the other.  If you lowered the `1024` to a much smaller value, this could be an optimization benefit.
- FYI, `MEDIUMBLOB` is limited to 16MB, with a 3-byte prefix.

Answer (score 0):

VARBINARY is not intended to store large data sets. For MariaDB it stores up to 1024 bytes and it will truncate data that does not fit in the column (or throw an error, if `SQL_MODE='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'` or `SQL_MODE='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'`.

If you intend to store data up to `10M`, there is no point in comparing VARBINARY and BLOB because some sort of BLOB (`MEDIUMBLOB`, `LONGBLOB`, etc.) is realistically the only option that you have.

Having said that, and not knowing much about your data structure, I would argue if it would not be better to store the data in a separate location (S3 for example) and use the database only to store pointers (links to the actual files).

Storing binary data in the database, most of the cases, is not ideal and it is not really scalable in the long run.

Comment: 10M was for 10 million rows. The data is small, 200-300 bytes.

Comment: "BLOB is realistically the only option that you have" -- There is `MEDIUMBLOB` with a limit of 16MB.

Comment: Meant some sort of BLOB. Edited my answer to clarify. The focus of my answer was on not to store anything like that in the database anyway.